# Can we use AWS SNS to send Web Push Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, web-push

Can we use AWS SNS Service to send Web Push Notification on Mobile and Web Browsers?

I read out the complete documentation of SNS but did not found anything related, Just want to confirm is that support Web Push Notification like below services.

https://sendpulse.com

https://www.moengage.com/

https://onesignal.com/

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to trigger Web Push notification from SNS but you have to do the actual sending yourself. [Here is an example](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-send-web-push-notifications-for-free-with-aws-and-without-firebase-19d02eadf1f7) that sends web push notifications from Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

For me, our supervisor only provided me an endpoint for AWS SNS which is written in PHP. I was able to integrate it in web app using Guzzle, a PHP HTTP Client.

Whenever AWS SNS got fired, Guzzle will be fired to calling my NodeJS back-end server. That NodeJS server sends web push notification.

Then in the front-end, I have a ServiceWorker which listens to the back-end.

When my front-end receives the push, it will show the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Currently AWS SNS doesn't support web push. Web push involves much more work than making some HTTP requests, for example you need to sign the HTTP requests with VAPID and you need a Javascript SDK to collect and manage subscriptions. Using a service specific for web push can save you a lot of work.

Comment: You need to [clearly disclose the affiliation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145583/211183)  when you mention your own product in an answer.

Comment: AWS SNS does support Webpush with FCM for Chrome/Firefox/Edge. I feel this answer is biased ( as you own PushPad) without much research.

Comment: @PratapKoritala Before accusing people, check the date of my answer. At that time AWS SNS did not support WebPush... I don't know if something has changed in the meantime. Also it really depends on what you need: web push does not involve only sending the HTTP request in the correct format.

Comment: @collimarco  SNS did support Web push for Chrome/Firefox/Edge before Apr 30 2018. Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/the-end-of-google-cloud-messaging-and-what-it-means-for-your-apps/

 Didn't mean to accuse, Just want to state that as this answer comes up in the first few search results of Google.

Comment: @PratapKoritala That article in your comment does not even mention WebPush! It is probably about native apps. Why do you say that it is about WebPush? In any case, if you can provide any official documentation about SNS + WebPush, I would be happy to update my answer.

Comment: @collimarco late reply as I lost this notification.  Amazon SNS can be used with FCM and APNS. And FCM works with Chrome Web/Mobile +  Firefox + Edge browsers. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/the-end-of-google-cloud-messaging-and-what-it-means-for-your-apps/

Comment: any update on this one? does it support now?